# Correct format for Mailing lists?

Tags: html, mailing-lists, plaintext

I came across this today

[lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/rtmpdump/2012-February/001827.html](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/rtmpdump/2012-February/001827.html)

This person has used HTML email instead of plain text. I put this question up so that people posting on mailing lists could have a reference of what is appropriate format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No HTML Mail, Please set your mailer to send only plain text messages to the
>   list.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mailing_list_guidelines

> Try not to use MIME: a lot of people use mailers which do not get on very well
>   with MIME.

http://freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/mailing-list-faq/etiquette.html

> in plain ascii text.

http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc1855

> Post HTML at your own risk. Keep in mind that not everyone uses mail or news
>   readers that can easily display HTML messages. Consequently, you will reach a
>   larger audience if you post in plain-text. Many people simply ignore HTML
>   messages, because it takes a nontrivial amount of effort to read them.

http://mozilla.org/about/forums/etiquette

> Please don't send HTML email. Send your email as plain text only.

http://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/MailingListEtiquette